# Ext js 4 how I can use store from another app?

Tags: include, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have BranchStore.js and BranchModel.js in my project. And I want use it in all my ext js 4 apps. Is it possible?

Comment: What is your question? Your either forgot a huge part or you should reread your own question. For sure you can use these files in any projects/apps you like.

Comment: I have five ext js apps in my project. How i can use these files without copy. I want placed them in one place, and then include in each apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put the code in script tags in your html, or grab them using Ext.syncRequire('path.js');  The regular Ext.require() call is asynchronous and the code will not be available immediately after the call to load it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but you need to load them with `Ext.require` in every project before you can use them.